# Writing a C program that removes every occurrence of a char except the last one

Tags: c

Im trying to write a C program that removes all occurrences of repeating chars in a string except the last occurrence.For example if I had the string

```
char word[]="Hihxiivaeiavigru";
```

output should be:

```
printf("%s",word);
hxeavigru
```

What I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>

int main()
{
     char word[]="Hihxiiveiaigru"; 

     for (int i=0;i<strlen(word);i++){
         if (word[i+1]==word[i]);
         memmove(&word[i], &word[i + 1], strlen(word) - i);
     }

     printf("%s",word);
     return 0;
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Save the index of the `last` one of those characters seen, then when you find the next, use `memmove` with `last` instead of `i`.

Comment: You don't seem to have made any provision for saving the last 'i'. But it is probably simpler and faster to work *backward* through the string, copying characters to a new string, then reverse the result.

Comment: 1) The main problem is that you need to keep track of which letters appear at least once.  2) Per your example, a character "repeats" if it occurs again ANYWHERE in the string - it doesn't have to be adjacent.  3) The example also suggests it's case-insensitive: "H" counts as a repeat of "h".  SUGGESTION: define a table for all possible characters (either A-Z, or all letters/numbers/punctuation: whatever the requirements state), initialize the table to all "0" (false), and change it to "true" the first instance of each character you find.  You might want to consider recursion..

Comment: @compscigirl the simplest method would be to apply the basci logic used to remove duplicates and then just iterate from right to left (backward traversal) instead of left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first write a function to determine if a `char ch` at a given position `i` is the last occurence of `ch` given a `char *`. Like,

```
bool isLast(char *word, char ch, int p) {
        p++;
        ch = tolower(ch);
        while (word[p] != '\0') {
                if (tolower(word[p]) == ch) {
                        return false;
                }
                p++;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Then you can use that to iteratively emit your desired characters like

```
int main() {
        char *word = "Hihxiivaeiavigru";
        for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                if (isLast(word, word[i], i)) {
                        putchar(word[i]);
                }
        }
        putchar('\n');
}
```

And (for completeness) I used

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
hxeavigru
```

Answer (score 2):

With short strings, any algorithm will do.  OP's attempt is O(n*n) (as well as other working answers and [@David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65261650/2410359) that identified OP's short-comings.)

But what if the string was thousands, millions in length?

Consider the following algorithm:  [@paulsm4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261350/writing-a-c-program-that-removes-every-occurrence-of-a-char-except-the-last-one/65261636#comment115376426_65261350)

```
   Form a `bool` array used[CHAR_MAX - CHAR_MIN + 1] and set each false.

   i,unique = n - 1;
   From the end of the string (n-1 to 0) to the front:
     if (character never seen yet) {  // used[] look-up
       array[unique] = array[i];       
       unique--;
     }
     Mark used[array[i]] as true (index from CHAR_MIN)
     i--;
   Shift the string "to the left" (unique - i) places
```

Solution is O(n)

---

Coding goal is too fun to just post a fully coded answer.

Answer (score 2):

Additional areas where you are currently hurting yourself.

- Your `for` loop must NOT increment the index, e.g. `for (int i=0; word[i];)`. This is because when you `memmove()` by `1`, you have just incremented the indexes. That also means the value to save for `last` is now `i - 1`.
- there should only be one call to `strlen()` in the program. You can simply subtract one from length each time `memmove()` is called.
- only increment your loop counter variable when `memmove()` is not called.

Additionally, avoid hardcoding strings. You shouldn't have to recompile your code just to test the results of `"Hihxiivaeiaigrui"` instead of `"Hihxiivaeiaigru"`. You shouldn't have to recompile just to remove all but the last `'a'` instead of the `'i'`. Either pass the string and character to find as arguments to your program (that's what `int argc, char **argv` are for), or prompt the user for input.

Putting it altogether you could do (presuming `word` is `1023` characters or less):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char word[MAXC];                        /* storage for word */
    strcpy (word, argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "Hihxiivaeiaigru");   /* copy to word */
    int find = argc > 2 ? *argv[2] : 'i',   /* character to find */
        last = -1;                          /* last index where find found */
    size_t len = strlen (word);             /* only compute strlen once */
    
    printf ("%s  (removing all but last %c)\n", word, find);
    for (int i=0; word[i];) {               /* loop over each char -- do NOT increment */
        if (word[i] == find) {              /* is this my character to find? */
            if (last != -1) {               /* if last is set */
                /* overwrite last with rest of word */
                memmove (&word[last], &word[last + 1], (int)len - last);
                last = i - 1;               /* last now i - 1 (we just moved it) */
                len = len - 1;
            }
            else {                          /* last not set */
                last = i;                   /* set it */
                i++;                        /* increment loop counter */
            }
        }
        else    /* all other chars */
            i++;                            /* just increment loop counter */
    }
    puts (word);    /* output result -- no need for printf (no coversions) */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rm_all_but_last_occurrence
Hihxiivaeiaigru  (removing all but last i)
Hhxvaeaigru
```

What if you want to use `"Hihxiivaeiaigrui"`? Just pass it as the 1st argument:

```
$ ./bin/rm_all_but_last_occurrence Hihxiivaeiaigrui
Hihxiivaeiaigrui  (removing all but last i)
Hhxvaeagrui
```

What if you want to use `"Hihxiivaeiaigrui"` and remove duplicate `'a'` characters? Just pass the string to search as the 1st argument and the character to find as the second:

```
$ ./bin/rm_all_but_last_occurrence Hihxiivaeiaigrui a
Hihxiivaeiaigrui  (removing all but last a)
Hihxiiveiaigrui
```

Nothing removed if only one of the characters:

```
$ ./bin/rm_all_but_last_occurrence Hihxiivaeiaigrui H
Hihxiivaeiaigrui  (removing all but last H)
Hihxiivaeiaigrui
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Aside:  Not that it is a great idea, "The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program," so a copy is not needed when `argv[1]` is available.

Comment: Yep, I'm just always hesitant to chop up `argv[x]` just in case I need it later `:)`

Comment: Thank you so much.This is great.Is there a way to remove all repeating chars except at the last occurrence instead of just for i only?

Comment: Yes, you can add an outer loop and loop over all the characters `[a-zA-Z]`. Rather than a brute force it would make sense to declare an empty array representing all ASCII characters, `char present[256] = {0};` and then loop `for (int i = 0; word[i]; i++) present[word[i]]++;` to increment the index for each ASCII character in `word`. Then for your outer loop, you would loop over the `present` array and remove duplicates for any index `> 2` (meaning char appears in `word` at least twice).

Answer (score 1):

> *Im trying to write a C program that removes all occurrences of repeating chars in a string except the last occurrence.*

Process the string (or word) from last character and move towards the first character of string (or word). Now, think of it as a problem where you have to remove all occurrence of a character from string and except the first occurrence. Since, we are processing the string from last character to first character, so, we have to move the characters, which are remain after removing duplicates, to the start of string once you have processed whole string and, if, there were duplicate characters found in the string. The complexity of this algorithm is `O(n)`.

Implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define INDX(x) (tolower(x) - 'a')

void remove_dups_except_last (char str[]) {
    int map[26] = {0};   /* to keep track of a character processed */
    size_t len = strlen (str);
    char *p = str + len;   /* pointer pointing to null character of input string */
    size_t i = 0;

    for (i = len; i != 0; --i) {
        if (map[INDX(str[i - 1])] == 0) {
            map[INDX(str[i - 1])] = 1;
            *--p = str[i - 1];
        }
    }

    /* if there were duplicates characters then only copy
     */
    if (p != str) {
        for (i = 0; *p; ++i) {
            str[i] = *p++;
        }
        str[i] = '\0';
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf ("Invalid number of arguments\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char str[1024] = {0};

    /* Assumption: the input string/word will contain characters A-Z and a-z
     * only and size of input will not be more than 1023.
     *
     * Leaving it up to you to check the valid characters in input string/word
     */
    strcpy (str, argv[1]);

    printf ("Original string : %s\n", str);

    remove_dups_except_last (str);

    printf ("Removed duplicated characters except the last one, modified string : %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Testcases output:

```
# ./a.out Hihxiivaeiavigru
Original string : Hihxiivaeiavigru
Removed duplicated characters except the last one, modified string : hxeavigru

#  ./a.out aa
Original string : aa
Removed duplicated characters except the last one, modified string : a

# ./a.out a 
Original string : a
Removed duplicated characters except the last one, modified string : a

# ./a.out TtYyuU
Original string : TtYyuU
Removed duplicated characters except the last one, modified string : tyU
```

Comment: Minor: `map[INDX(str[i - 1])]` deserves a prior test to determine if character is a letter  yet this is speedy O(n) code - UV.  `strcpy (str, argv[1]);` not needed.  Could use `remove_dups_except_last (argv[1]);` (yet I do like the copy).

Answer (score 0):

You can re-iterate to get each characters of your string, then if it is not "i" and not the last occurrence of the i, copy to a new string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>

int main() {
    
char word[]="Hihxiiveiaigru"; 
char newword[10000];
char* ptr = strrchr(word, 'i'); 

int index=0;
int index2=0;
while (index < strlen(word)) {
    if (word[index]!='i' || index ==(ptr - word)) {
       newword[index2]=word[index];
       index2++;
     }
   index++; 
}

printf("%s",newword);
        return 0;
}
```